# Automatically updating input or inputfield

Tags: dynamic, inputfield

Is it feasible to make an input field, that or similar functionality, that could be constantly updated while typing or editing, without clicking Enter button?
The example is as follows:

```
{InputField[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[Hash[x]]}
```

I'd be glad to type in the field with each symbol Hash would updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the option `ContinuousAction->True` to get the desired behavior, but this option only works for the Boxes, Number and String types. For example:

```
x = "";
{
    InputField[Dynamic[x], Boxes, ContinuousAction->True],
    Dynamic[ToExpression[x, StandardForm, Hash]]
}
```